# Simple count backwards in if clause, causes index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Everything works, except the back-button has a flaw which I don't quite understand.
I found a fix, but I want to understand why the code behaves so bizarre.
Array has a nil object at the end.

Supposed to be but not working code (Index beyond bounds):

```
- (IBAction)back-button:(id)sender
{
    currentArrayIndex--;

    if (currentArrayIndex == 0)
    {
        currentArrayIndex = [array count];
    }
}
```

Here's the fixed but seemingly faulty code:

```
- (IBAction)back-button:(id)sender
{

    currentArrayIndex--;

    if (currentArrayIndex == -1)
    {
        currentArrayIndex = [array count] -1;
    }
    else if (currentArrayIndex == -2)
    {
        currentArrayIndex = [array count];
    }
}
```

Now mathematically and programmatically it doesn't make sense.

The code for the "next"-button is very clean and clear, and works perfectly in round-robin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest index is `count - 1`, since arrays are zero based indexed. The lowest index is therefore `0`, and if you want to round robin over your array in reverse order, the second code is correct (you can remove the `else if` part). Last but not least, make sure that `currentArrayIndex` is a signed integer, otherwise it will never become `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are indexed from 0. So the first object is `array[0]` (or equivelantly `[array objectAtIndex:0]`). So the second has index `1 = 2 - 1`, 3rd has `2 = 3 - 1`, and the last '`[array count]`-th' has index `[array count] - 1`. So from this you can see that `[array count]` is one past the last valid index, and thus indeed out of bounds.

You can switch the order of your steps to make it work correctly and make it maybe more intuitive again:

```
- (IBAction)back-button:(id)sender
{
  if (currentArrayIndex == 0)
  {
    currentArrayIndex = [array count];
  }

  currentArrayIndex--;
}
```

Comment: With this switching, the code still causes an error of beyond bounds, I will upvote your answer, as it explained it more intuitevly, but since it had erroneous code, I'll accept the answer below, ok?

Comment: At which point in the code are you actually using `currentArrayIndex`? You should use it after the decrement, or possibly before the `if`.